# Masking inputs any field and values

Tags: jquery, html, masking

I would like to know how to get the length of an input and replace everything between the values start and end but leave 2 chars and both ends.

I don't want to predefine the length as I want it to work on any input with any value and still be able to read the values with PHP when form submitted.

**Input:** `Hello world street 12`
**Output:** `He*** ***** ****** 12`

**Input:** `185445414631`
**Output:** `18********31`

**Js lib:** 
https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin

**My code:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/k4y0ctho/1/

Comment: Mask the string leaving first 2 characters and last 1. This is the pattern right.?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay first 2 and last 2 sir

Comment: And the string would be having numbers always or it can be alphabets as shown in example ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay both sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your output is acceptable on other field, this might be useful

```js
$("#input").on("keyup", function() {
 
  var input = $(this).val().split("")
  var res = $.map(input, (el, ix) => {
    return ix < 2 || ix > input.length - 3? el:"*"
  })

  $("#output").html(res.join(""));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="password" id="input" />
<br><span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: thats a good start, better what i have right now but its should be the other way around with the masking :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery what you can do is :

```
// Util function to mask the value
function maskValue(value) {
    if (typeof value !== 'string' || value.length <= 4) {
        return value;
    }
    return value.split('').map((v, i) => { return (i > 1 && i < value.length - 2 ? '*' : v); }).join('');
}

// actual value (not masked)
let actualValue = '';

// keyup event to handle new input and mask the value
$("#my-input").on("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.key === 'Backspace') {
        actualValue = actualValue.substring(0, actualValue.length - 1);
    }
    else {
        actualValue += event.key;
    }
    $('#my-input').val(maskValue(actualValue));
});
```

Please keep in mind that this is not perfect as it only supports normal keys (letters, numbers, symbols) and the backspace button.