# Hide only few character in a password

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to show only first and last character of a password with javascript?
Like this:
***** -> e***4

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: It would not be complicated to use the key event of an input to store the password in a var and use a copy where you replace the content with '*'. Have you tried ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is **NOT** a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders *but you need to help yourself first. :-)* You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is there *any* reason why is this desirable? Users don't need to see what their passwords are... not when they're typing on the screen.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46281083/492258)

Comment: It's uniquely to allow user to have a quick idea of the structure of his field password after entering it in a input type...

Comment: Great! I will try. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value of password to hidden values, and make its type property from `password` to `text`:

```js
$('#hintPassword').click(function(){
  $("#hiddenPassword").val($('#password').val());
  
  var passwordHint = $('#password').val().replace(/(?!^).(?!$)/g, '•');
  
  $('#password').attr('type', 'text');
  $('#password').val(passwordHint);
});

$('#hidePassword').click(function(){
  $('#password').attr('type', 'password');
  $('#password').val($("#hiddenPassword").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenPassword">
<input type="password" id="password" value="pa$$w0rd"> <button id="hintPassword">Hint</button> <button id="hidePassword">Hide</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is a bit strange here since you have to count the amount of chars between the first and last letter. But you can do it with substrings or arrays much simpler.

```js
var password = 'Example';
var parts = password.split('');
var len = parts.length;
var chiffred = parts.map(function(val, index) {
  if (0 === index || (len - 1) === index) {

  }
  else {
val = '*';
  }
  return val;
});
chiffred = chiffred.join('');
console.log(chiffred);
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go!
You just need to get the concept of dealing with strings with substr and slice.
And just some regex too.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('password');

input.addEventListener('keydown', function(){
 if(input.value.length > 1){
   input.value = input.value.substr(0, 1) + input.value.substr(1, input.value.length).replace(/[\S\s]/g, "*");
  }
});
```

```html
<input type = "text" id = "password" />
```